# Appending a <div> to the horizontal center of another <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to create a little menu that changes position as the user scrolls.  I've come up for this for a style - http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/S8tyn/

As you can see, the dots are appended to each text `<div>` element, and it looks like this.
[image]

However, this looks very ugly.  How can I center each dot beneath each text div?  I've tried doing things like `text-align: center` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the css style of `margin: auto` to center the child div.

http://jsfiddle.net/S8tyn/1/

Comment: That works - hadn't thought of setting the margin to auto.  I thought that _append_ would add it after the element, not as a child.  So if I'm getting this right, the child element is appended into a space as large as the parent element (which is how wide the text is) and margin 0 auto; just centers it between that space?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In fact, append adds the items after the last item within the parent div (prepend adds it before the first item). Since the parent is empty both have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your style to next

```
.unselectedcircle
{
  background: grey;
  position: relative; 
  top: 32px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S8tyn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for your question: 
**added left and margin-left**

```
.unselectedcircle
{
background: grey;
position: relative; 
top: 32px;
border-radius: 100%;
width: 10px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-5px;
height: 10px;
}
```

[updated link](http://jsfiddle.net/S8tyn/3/)

Comment: This is a good alternative to margin 0 auto.  Would I be incorrect to assume that this would have more compatibility with browsers like older IE?

Comment: I believe no bcz these are purely on a calculation basis. margin-left is in -ve which is half of the actual width.